# Joomla 2.5.9 Wrong redirect after Read more -> Login

Tags: redirect, joomla, authentication

I´ve a strange Joomla 2.5.9 problem where I do not know if it´s a bug or a setting issue. 
Anyway my problem is I ´ve created a menu item kind "Blog List", choosed a category and set the "access" of the articles to "registered" and "show unauthorized access links" to yes. Now the user can see the articles, but is redirected to the login if he clicks "read more". 
steps can be seen here (-> http://tinyurl.com/bldbvx4)

So far so good. Unfortunately the return URL for the article is not created correctly.

I ´ve created a demo installation which illustrates my problem. 
http://seminare-gratz.de/Joomla_2/index.php/problem

Login:
demo
demo

If I click "Koala" and log-in in the next step, Joomla tries to redirect me to:
http://seminare-gratz.de/Joomla_2/index.php/%2FJoomla_2%2Findex.php%2Fproblem%3Fid%3D25%3Akoala
correct would be:
http://seminare-gratz.de/Joomla_2/index.php/problem/25-koala

To solve this issue I tried to cut the wrong part with htaccess (failed)

Any clue how to fix this?

Thankful for any help,

Tony

Answer (score 1):

Okay, got it. For everyone else having this problem. I did a template override of:

components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php

and cutted the urlencode in line 149.

```
        //$link->setVar('return', base64_encode(urlencode($returnURL)));
    $link->setVar('return', base64_encode($returnURL));
```

with this hack it works ...

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have given Access level to register so normal users are not allowed to read this article. So you kindly change access level registered to public.

Comment: no, i think that´s not the point. joomla has a feature for this called "show unauthorized access links". (-> http://tinyurl.com/bldbvx4)